# Angular 7 - Save HTTP Requests to Local storage

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-forms

I'm working with angular 7, sending requests to my backend using angular httpclient
and i'm intercepting requests in case of failure and save it to the local storage in order to retry when the connection is stable

> import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

```
this.localStorage.getItem<HttpRequest<any>[]>('failed').subscribe((failed:HttpRequest<any>[]) => {
                    console.log(typeof request);
                    if(failed==null)
                    {
                        var newFailed =new Array<HttpRequest<any>>();
                        newFailed.push(request);
                        this.localStorage.setItem('failed', newFailed).subscribe(() => {});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        failed.push(request);
                        this.localStorage.setItem('failed', failed).subscribe(() => {});
                    }
                    console.log(failed);
                });
```

my issue is that when fetching the array again in another code, the objects in my array isn't of type HttpRequest so i can't loop on them and pass to httpclient to retry that request again.

any solutions ?

Comment: You could intercept all of the HttpRequests and keep them in a map/array, then remove any request that succeeds. On fail, the request would remain in the map, which you could then pass to your retry logic.

Comment: yes i know, but i need that array to be saved in localstorage to be persistent in case of refresh

Comment: Can you JSON.stringify(yourArray) when setting it to local storage, then JSON.parse(yourArray) when retrieving it? Alternatively you could JSON.stringify each HttpRequest and fetch it by a unique key.